# Phonegap - HTML does not display image from storage

Tags: html, cordova, file-transfer

I'm using FileTransfer plugin to download an image from a remote server.

The image is stored in "storage/emulated/0/" - using the following code:

```
function downloadFile(fileDownloadName){
    //console.log('downloadFile');
    window.requestFileSystem(
        LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT,
        0,
        function(fileSystem){
            //console.log('onRequestFileSystemSuccess');
            fileSystem.root.getFile(
                'dummy.html',
                {create: true, exclusive: false},
                function(fileEntry){
                    //console.log('onGetFileSuccess!');
                    var path = fileEntry.toURI().replace('dummy.html', '');
                    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                    fileEntry.remove();

                    fileTransfer.download(
                        'https://www.myserver.com/imagens/' + fileDownloadName,
                        path + fileDownloadName,
                        function(file) {
                            //console.log('download complete: ' + file.toURI());
                            return path + fileDownloadName;
                        },
                        function(error) {
                            console.log('download error source ' + error.source);
                            console.log('download error target ' + error.target);
                            console.log('upload error code: ' + error.code);
                        }
                    );  
                },
                fail
            );
        },
        fail
    );
}
```

So, I'm pointing the path + fileDownloadName to SRC of my image, but the image does not appear.

```
var location = path + fileDownloadName;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(location, function(oFile) {
   oFile.file(function(readyFile) {
      var reader= new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend= function(evt) {
      $(".circle-perfil").css('background-image', 'url(' + evt.target.result + ')');
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(readyFile); 
});
```

Is there something wrong I'm doing? Should I have to store the image in another folder? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: How you are pointing the path + fileDownloadName to src image ? plz share that line as well.

Comment: If you are using img tag then try 'src' and not background-image. and did the evt.target.result returns correct path of image, have you checked in console.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **img** tag then set its image as:

```
$(".circle-perfil").css('background', 'url(' + evt.target.result + ')');
```

or

```
$(".circle-perfil").css('content', 'url(' + evt.target.result + ')');
```

In case of **div** or **span**

```
$(".circle-perfil").css('background-image', 'url(' + evt.target.result + ')');
```

I had set it like:

```
var image = document.getElementById('cameraPic');
image.src = 'path/of/image file';
```